# Add another image next to logo - Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I need your help. I've got:
[image]

I need to have image in the red box (example), next to logo.
My header.php:
https://pastebin.com/raw/qxgUiQwQ

And a css of the box which include a logo:

```
    /* ========================================= Theme Header. ========================================= */
.mainmenucontainer {
    background:url(images/mainmenu.png) left top repeat-x;
}
#logo {
    background:url(images/logo-bg.png) left top repeat-x;
    display:flex;
    align-items:center;
    height:90px;
    text-align:left;
}
#logo img {
    max-height:95%;
}
.site_ttl {
    float:left;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    line-height:normal;
    color: #fff;
    text-transform: none;
}
.headersearch {
    float:right;
    display:flex;
    align-items:center;
    height:45px;
    margin-right:20px;
}
@media screen and (min-width:1024px) {
    .headersearch { 

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the existing image set as a background element, either edit the image to include the new image or overlay the image by editing your header code. It's not really achievable by changing your CSS (this is not strictly true, you could do it with a pseudo element and some funky margins and alignment, but that would be an utter hack).